# Inicializar Array en Constructor PHP

Tags: php, array, class

Tengo el siguiente código tengo una clase principal, la cual manda el valor data a la clase prueba, pero al momento de invocar al metodo getArreglo, no imprime el valor que necesito, me marca

```
class Prueba{
// data es: "valor1-valor2-valor3"
$arreglo;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->arreglo= array();
        $this->arreglo=explode("-", $data);
    }

    public function getArreglo(){
        echo $this->$arreglo[1];//Aquí es donde marca el error 'Undefined variable: arreglo'
    }
//Debería imprimir valor1 al llamar a getArreglo pero no lo hace
}
```

Comment: Te sobra un `$`: `echo $this->arreglo[1];`.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, voto por cerrarla como *error tipográfico*.

Comment: @Trauma me parece también le hace falta creo identificar que modificador de acceso tiene la propiedad `$arreglo` es decir no debería tener por ejemplo `public`?

Comment: @anonimo No hace falta, por defecto son `public`. De todas formas, la accede desde una funcion-miembro de la propia clase, así que no hay problema.

Comment: Esta línea sobra en el constructor: `$this->arreglo= array();` ¿por qué?, porque [`explode` devuelve un arreglo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php), por lo tanto, cuando asignas el resultado de `explode` a una variable ya declaras esa variable como `array`. Siempre que vayas a usar una función revisa la parte del Manual de PHP que dice **Valores devueltos**, para saber cómo habría que usarla, evitando código redundante.

Comment: @Trauma, [según el estándar PSR-2: _«Visibility MUST be declared on all properties.»_](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#42-properties). No recuerdo en otras versiones de PHP, pero en la versión 7, este código daría error debido a que `$arreglo` no tiene indicado su modificar de acceso.

Comment: @A.Cedano Tienes razón, confusión mía con usar `var`. Gracias por la corrección :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Hay ciertamente un error de sintaxis en tu código, porque cuando se usa `$this` en una clase, los nombres de los miembros no llevan el símbolo `$` [tal y como dice el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.properties.php):

> Dentro de los métodos de una clase, se puede acceder a las propiedades
>   no estáticas utilizando `->` (el operador de objeto):
>   `$this->propiedad` (donde *propiedad* es el nombre de la propiedad). A
>   las propiedades estáticas se puede acceder utilizando `::` (doble dos
>   puntos): `self::$propiedad`. Véase [la palabra reservada 'static'](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php)
>   para más información sobre la diferencia entre propiedades estáticas y
>   no estáticas.

Esto puede ser confuso en la práctica, porque en las propiedades estáticas sí se usa la `$`, pero combinando la llamada con `self`, no con `$this`.

---

Pero hay más errores en tu código.

No sé en otras versiones de PHP, pero en la versión 7 no puedes declarar `$arreglo` en la clase sin modificador de acceso, debes por tanto indicar explícitamente si es `public, private, protected`... de lo contrario tendrás el error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$arreglo' (T_VARIABLE),
>   expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

El [estándar PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#42-properties) lo dice con toda claridad:

> Visibility MUST be declared on all properties.
>
> ---
>
> La visibilidad DEBE ser declarada en todas las propiedades.

---

Otra cosa es que, en el constructor, esta línea sobra:

```
    $this->arreglo= array();
```

¿Por qué? [Porque `explode` devuelve un array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php), por tanto, cuando asignas el resultado de `explode` a una variable, ya la estás declarando como array de por sí.

---

Otra cosa es que tu método no contempla situaciones como que el arreglo no tenga índice `1` o esté vacío. Esto se puede hacer con un ternario, verificando con `empty`:

```
echo (!empty($this->arreglo[1])) ? $this->arreglo[1] : "No existe este índice";
```

Sé que tu método `getArreglo()` es a modo de ejemplo, no tendría mucho sentido en un método devolver solamente un índice fijo de un array. Pero señalando esto quiero indicar que los métodos de una clase deben ser escritos pensando también cómo manejar ciertas situaciones erróneas.

---

Clase completa aplicando todo lo dicho:

```
class Prueba{
    private $arreglo;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->arreglo=explode("-", $data);
    }

    public function getArreglo(){

        echo (!empty($this->arreglo[1])) ? $this->arreglo[1] : "No existe este índice";
    }
}
```

Algunas pruebas:

```
$mPrueba=new Prueba("");
$mPrueba->getArreglo();
echo PHP_EOL;
$mPrueba=new Prueba("valor1-valor2");
echo PHP_EOL;
$mPrueba->getArreglo();
$mPrueba=new Prueba("valor1");
echo PHP_EOL;
$mPrueba->getArreglo();
```

**Salida:**

```
No existe este índice

valor2
No existe este índice
```

Si no usáramos el ternario, la salida sería:

```
Error(s), warning(s):
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in source_file.php on line 12
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in source_file.php on line 12


valor2
```